# Can't find package android.bluetooth

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I need to use Bluetooth for an app I am developing and after typing `import android.`
I notice that `bluetooth` is missing.

Where is it? I am using Eclipse and am not too familiar with the IDE so perhaps I am missing something?

I have done all the updates and so I believe that I have the latest SDK installed.

Comment: `android.bluetooth` was introduced in API level 5 (a.k.a Android 2.0). Is your project configured to at least that level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `android.bluetooth` and is only available since API Level 5. So you must check your project setup.

Comment: My god that was a fast response!

Comment: Yes, I realized that just after my post and came back to delete it but you are just too quick :P  Thanks for the help though!